Curious definition of ordering in Gibbard's "Manipulation of Voting Schemes: A General Result"
I'm reading Alan Gibbard's Manipulation of Voting Schemes: A General Result and I'm a bit astonished by his definition of the concept of ordering.
I'm talking about the following condition parge 594: $$(1b): \forall x, y, z,  (xPz \implies (xPy \lor yPz))$$
Why would $y$ be forcefully comparable with either $x$ or $z$?

Note that next he defines $x R y$ as $\neg y P x$. If we take the contrapositive of (1b), we get:
$$
(\neg x P y \wedge \neg y P z ) \to \neg x P z,
$$
which then translates to the usual transitivity condition on $R$,
$$
(y R x \wedge z R y) \to z R x.
$$
Also note that condition (1.a) gives in this notation,
$$
\neg (x P y \wedge y P x) \equiv (y R x \vee x R y),
$$
which states that $R$ is complete.
So condition (1.a) and (1.b) simply require $R$ to be a complete and transitive relation.

I had this implication, but I don't understand why R total reflexive transitive => (1.b). Isn't something more assumed?

OK, I've formalized in Coq the correspondence between the "math standard" preference relations and Gibbard's ordering: see the Github repo
